# Celery tasks run twice in the background once Flask application is run, why?

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, celery

I'm building a Flask web application, where I want some asynchronous background tasks to be started once the Flask application is run. I've been reading about the examples and manuals regarding Flask and Celery, e.g. [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) but in many examples the Celery background tasks are bound to the Flask routing functions. That is, the Celery background functions are run when a request for a specific URL-bound Flask function is received from the client.

What I want, in addition to this, is to have Celery background tasks started the moment the Flask application is run. I have created a minimal working example into this post (`myapp.py`, Flask + Celery + RabbitMQ):

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

celery = Celery(app.name, backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')

@celery.task
def long_background_task1():
    print("Doing the heavy background job 1...")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Finished the heavy background job 1!")
    return("This is the return from the heavy background job 1!")

@celery.task
def long_background_task2():
    print("Doing the heavy background job 2...")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Finished the heavy background job 2!")
    return("This is the return from the heavy background job 2!")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return("This is the index page")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # At the start of the Flask application, start also one or more background Celery tasks
    long_background_task1.delay()
    long_background_task2.delay()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So when `myapp.py` is run, I want the Celery tasks `long_background_task1` and `long_background_task2` to be started and run on the background. If I start the Celery worker in the terminal with the command:

```
celery -A myapp.celery worker --loglevel=INFO
```

I get the following output:

[image]

So Celery seems to be okay! Next, when I run `myapp.py` I get the following output in Celery terminal (click the image to enlarge):

[image]

So the Celery tasks are indeed started in the background, but they are run two times! What causes this?

**So my question is: How can make the Celery background tasks start on the background only once?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution myself. I was checking at this post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/2chlio/does_init_get_run_twice_in_my_case/

And I noticed the comment:

"The development server does all sorts of things that won't happen in production to make sure that changes to files are loaded into the application live."

So I changed in `myapp.py`:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

to

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

and the problem was fixed! No running the tasks twice anymore.